# Dependent variables, regression

Tags: independence, quantile-regression

I am trying do make some descriptive statistic.
In my dataset I have ID, Age, time from start of being registered, sex, birth-place. The time from start of being registered minus date 15 June 2019 generates the amount of years the subject has being registered at the date of obtaining data.

My data is strongly right skewed as many other health register data, therefor I wish use Quantile regression.
My question is, can I use the amount of years the subject has being registered as my dependent variable (outcomes)? Is it correct to use quantile regression without having cases?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Wishes 
Homayoun

Comment: Your question is confusing. "Descriptive statistics" typically means things like mean, standard deviation, inter-quartile range, sample size. You don't need to fit a model to do this. However if you want to fit a model, you may not be able to use "years of subject being registered" as an outcome because it may not a continuous response, but rather a censored response which requires special models. Finally it is not clear what you mean by "cases".

Comment: 1651 cases and no controlsI, however the positively skewed shape made me to consider ways to use test for correlation, co-linearity, multi linearity, different in and between groups, and used interquantile test as you mentioned. My problem begins her I cant find out which variable I should use as outcome if not "years of subject being registered" as you suggested. Can you please develop it for me how to censor variable? Do you mean value 0, 1? How should I get that special model? I can mention that I am using Stata. Thanks again.

Comment: Please help. My dataset and my purposed dependent variable is give out exactly what you see here: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rdiagnosticplots.pdf. The price and my variable "years of subject being registered" give exactly the same results as in https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rdiagnosticplots.pdf, Please guide me to understand if my choice is still wrong.